# Get Vimeo Thumbnail URL from Json

Tags: json, wordpress, vimeo-api

I'm using the following to generate the thumbnail from a Vimeo video in Wordpress via the functions.php file:

```
function get_vimeo_thumb($id, $size = 'thumbnail_small')
{
  if(get_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id))
  {
    $thumb_image = get_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id);
  }
  else
  {
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" . $id . ".json" ) );
$thumb_image = $json[0]->$size;

 set_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id, $thumb_image, 2629743);
  }
  return $thumb_image;
}
```

And then the following in my theme files:

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(43096888) . '">';
?>
```

But I now want to use the oEmbed link to get the data:

https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/43096888

The reference I need is thumbnail_url but I can't figure out how to get it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This will get what you want:

```
$url = 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $id));
$thumb_image = $json->thumbnail_url;
```

If you want a thumbnail with an overlay of a burned-in play button, access `thumbnail_url_with_play_button` instead of `thumbnail_url`.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing, am I to just replace the middle bit so I have this then:

    function get_vimeo_thumb($id, $size = 'thumbnail_small')
    {
  if(get_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id))
  {
    $thumb_image = get_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id);
  }
      else
      {
    $url = 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/';
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $id));
    $thumb_image = $json->thumbnail_url;
    
        set_transient('vimeo_' . $size . '_' . $id, $thumb_image, 2629743);
      }
      return $thumb_image;
    }

Comment: Make sure you are hitting `https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json`, not `vimeo.com/api/oembed.json`

Comment: Sorry the https is removing itself from the message, I basically have what I have in my question but just put your bit in the middle and not working, what am I doing wrong? thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you share a Github Gist with your full code? The code snippet I shared originally works just fine for me.